# PHP variable contains loop

Tags: php, email

Here's the scenario, I have a form that contains checkboxes and when submitted will be sent to a certain email. I am trying to put the checked items into one string. Like option1 option2 option 3

Here is what I have done for now:

```
echo $message = foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){ echo $checkbox . "\r\n";}
```

Desired output of $message:

```
Option1
Option2
Option3
```

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php) is a control structure. It does not `return` anything

Answer (score 2):

Please make it as:

```
$message = '';
if (! empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {
    $message .= $checkbox . "\r\n";
  }
}
```